# Export Cronbach Alpha Results - R

Tags: r, psych

I'm following [THIS](https://www.r-bloggers.com/five-ways-to-calculate-internal-consistency/) R Blogger tutorial to calculate Cronbach alpha, which works perfectly.  I'd like to learn how to export the results, either into a data.frame or text file.  Any ideas how I might be able to export the results from the following code: `psych::alpha(d)`?  Note, I looked at the stargazer package, but couldn't get it work work with Cronbach outputs only regression and descriptive statistics.  Thank you.

Comment: The usual approach to getting a text file dump of console output is to use `capture.output` or `sink`. (It's been asked many time before so I don't want to repeat an existing answer.) If these functions do not provide an adequate path to success, then do read [MCVE]. (Links to blogs are NOT considered adequate effort at coding, IMO anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output can be saved as a txt file this way. You can also subset the object created with the alpha function using the $ operator to get only the information you are interested in.

```
setwd("~/Desktop")
out <- psych::alpha(d)
capture.output(out,file = "alpha.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

As is true of everything R, there are many ways of doing what you want to do.  The first thing is to look at the help menu for the function (in this case ?alpha).  There you will see that a number of objects are returned from the alpha function.  (This is what is listed in Values part of the help file.)

When you print the output of alpha you are shown just a subset of these objects.  However, to see the entire list of objects that are returned, use the "str" command

```
my.results <- alpha(my.data)
str(my.results)     #or just list the names of the objects
 names(my.alpha)
 [1] "total"         "alpha.drop"    "item.stats"    "response.freq" "keys"          "scores"        "nvar"          "boot.ci"      
 [9] "boot"          "Unidim"        "Fit"           "call"          "title"
```

You can then choose to capture any of those objects for your own use.
Thus

```
my.alpha <- alpha(ability) #use the ability data set in the psych package
my.alpha #will give the normal (and nicely formatted output)
totals <- my.alpha$total   #just get one object from my.alpha
totals                     #show that object
```

will  produce a single line (without the fancy output):

```
raw_alpha std.alpha   G6(smc) average_r      S/N         ase      mean        sd
 0.8292414 0.8307712 0.8355999 0.2347851 4.909159 0.006384736 0.5125148 0.2497765
```

You can do this for any of the objects returned.  Most of us who write packages print what we think are the essential elements of the output of the function, but include other useful information. We also allow for other functions (such as summary) to print out other information.

So, using the example from above,

```
summary(my.alpha)  #prints the rounded to 2 decimals my.alpha$total object
Reliability analysis   
 raw_alpha std.alpha G6(smc) average_r S/N    ase mean   sd
      0.83      0.83    0.84      0.23 4.9 0.0064 0.51 0.25
```

A final word of caution.  Many of us do  not  find alpha a particularly useful statistic to describe the structure of a scale.  You might want to read the tutorial on how to find coefficient omega using the psych package at

http://personality-project.org/r/psych/HowTo/R_for_omega.pdf